# Directory listing and static paths with grunt-contrib-connect

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I'm trying to get `grunt-contrib-connect` to work with a directory listing but I also need some static paths as well.

This configuration allows me to browse static html files and it works fine.

```
server: {
   options: {
      base: 'src/',
      open: true
   }
}
```

The issue is the html files use resources outside of the base directory. So I did the following which allows access to the static resources but the directory listing no longer works.

```
server: {
   options: {
      base: 'src/',
      open: true,
      middleware: function(connect) {
         return [
            connect().use('/img', connect.static('./img')),
            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
            connect.static(yeomanConfig.app)
         ];
      }
   }
}
```

Is it possible for me to have the directory listings and the static paths?